# "The File Exist" error while publishing

Tags: publishing, dd4t, templating

We have DD4T based application, we start getting below error while publishing pages, it says file exist.

We removed all temp files from `c:\windows\temp` and `C:\Users\[MTSUser]\AppData\Local\Temp` but still we are getting same "The file exist" error, I am not sure how Tridion stores files on these location but it didn't help.

[image]

Comment: are you able to see preview?

Comment: @raj yes i am able to preview pages and all CP's as well. Also one more thing when i see in publishing queue it says 
"the number of render failure is exceeded its specified limit 0" and when i click on processed items it says "The File Exist"

Comment: I don't know how but it seems to be fixed , when i checked it again it started working. so might me that clean up fixed it.